# android application crashes when rotating the screen

Tags: java, android, android-layout, rotation

My app crashec when rotating the device. I know it crashes because whenI rotate the screen it tries to create new View to draw and display but how can it create the view and display it properly on the launch but crashes when trying to create the second new view?

I dont know what part of my code I should post here? Can you give a clue to solve this problem?

---

I found something usefull. I put try/catch statement and now when I rotate the device, it doesnt crash but displays a blank page, when I re-rotate to the old position it display the page. here is my code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("my_error", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

but eclipse cannot catch the exception.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You will receive a clue on solving your problem when you give us a clue on how to help answer your question. Specifically, what are the errors you encounter when you rotate your screen? Post your LogCat output and the relevant portion of your source code.

Comment: IF you dont  add your logs or dont point out what part of code causes the exception then there will be general solutions .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two possible ways to do this:

1) You don't care about the orientation change of the screen and you just want to be "resized". Just add the following properties in your Manifest file:

```
<activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" ... />
```

and add this lines of code in your activity:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
            // do nothing, just override
}
```

2) You do care about the orientation change. Then there are a couple of things that you should know about the activity lifecycle in an orientation change.
Firstly the `onConfigurationChanged()` is called and you should store in a `Bundle` everything that you need. For example the user has editted an `EditText` and you should save the value.

Why to do that? Because afterwards the `onCreate()` method will be called again in order for you to implement a different layout or alter something in the `View`s. You should then take the previously saved `Bundle` and restore the variables that you saved in your newly created layout.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the `android:configChanges="orientation"` to your activity

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"/>
```

if you given like this, then oncreate will not called if your screen orientation is changed.
If you need more information about this you can check [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you can do:

1) Ignore screen orientation changes. If your app is only designed for portrait mode, most likely it won't look good in landscape mode and vice versa. Best is to specify the target orientation in your activities.

2) If you want to allow orientation changes, then you should have written some code re-create the view with different/modified layout. Mind sharing the code with us?

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
//Override this and recreate your view or set adapter here
    }
```

Dont forget to add `android:configChanges="orientation"` in your manifest.

On a side note you can fix orientation through manifest like this -
`android:screenOrientation="portrait"`

Comment: This is BAD! In onConfigurationChanged() you never recreate the View or change the UI! You just save variables.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your Activity tag in the manifest:

```
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

This will cause that the activity is not recreated on rotation change.
The flag **sreenSize** is for newer devices(API level 13 or higher), with including only the **orientation** flag the activity will stil recreate when rotating on devices running API level 13 or higher.